# Querying the client periodically for update via sockets-Reusing ports

Tags: java, sockets, timer

using the Controller.java, I' implementing the run() in NetworkDiscovery.java which queries all the machine in the subnet . The active machines reply with their status. This happens at regular intervals.

```
public class Controller {
NetworkDiscovery n;
public static int discoveryInterval=2000;
PM pmList;
List pmlist=(List) new PM();

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException{
Timer t1=new Timer();
t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NetworkDiscovery(), 2000, discoveryInterval);
}

public class NetworkDiscovery extends TimerTask{

InetAddress controllerIP;
int controllerPort;

NetworkDiscovery() throws UnknownHostException {
    controllerIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    controllerPort=4455;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[5000];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
        DatagramSocket dSock = new DatagramSocket(4445);
        dSock.receive(packet);
//implementation related code follows
**dSock.close();**
}
}
```

On the client's side a similar Datagram socket is opened and objects are received/sent.

The problem is that on the COntroller's side, I'm executing NetworkDiscovery's run() after a specific time interval and during the second execution it says -

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Since I'm closing the Controller's socket by close(), why does it still show that this address is already being in use? How can I make sure that during the next iteration, the controller starts over fresh call of networkDiscovery?

Comment: are you sure close() gets executed? maybe an exception or something occurs before that and the close() part gets skipped. If that is the case try using finally.

Comment: @peshkira- The close() doesn't get executed. Double checked with the ports open while execution. How can I proceed to solve this?

Comment: well, if the close() method doesn't get executed, then probably an exception is thrown before that and the flow of the program skips to the catch block. Since, you didn't post the whole part of the implementation my only idea is that you add a finally block after the catch block and call dSock.close() there. However, as I said, I cannot be sure that this was the cause of the problem as code is missing.

Comment: @PESHKIRA- True. I figured out that the problem lay elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the second task starts before the first was completly executed? Have you tried to insert debug messages and see if the first task was finished?